# MQTT: Raw Header - Dont't understand this one

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am developing a small MQTT client to subscribe to and to monitor certain topics. For the most part, it works well assuming a one-byte length info (2nd byte). But I sometimes get this subscribe 0x30 response, that I can't understand. It seems to have a multi byte length but neither length byte has its MSB set.

Header

`0000: 3031312700127b6c756d6f7375727d2f   011'..{lumosur}/
0010: 6461746574696d65323032302d30322d   datetime2020-02-
0020: 30342032333a32313a3437311900127b   04 23:21:471...{`

How to figure it out?

Thanks for your help.

mm.

Comment: Can't be a multi-byte length. This is just a PUBLISH pack of length 0x31. Why do think otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Though I was staring at that problem for hours, it was just after I posted the question that it dawned on me. The protocol doesn't have a problem: I was reading the data wrongly.

This is a binary protocol so I have to read the blocks according to the length field in the header. I didn't do that correctly so the data I assumed was correct header data actually wasn't aligned correctly.

Sorry to bother you :D

Michaela